# Using Argparse within a Class __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, arguments, argparse

Is it possible to use Argparse from within a class and if so, how would you get the parameters to the parser? Is there a better way of going about this? Here is my code so far:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("num_players", help="Number of players", type=int)
        ...
        args = parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = Game()
```

Also Is there a way of supplying optional arguments such as `--verbose`?

Comment: It is highly unlikely to be the best design. The `Game` class should probably not care how it was initialized, and it should probably know nothing about command line arguments. You will be better off parsing the CLI args outside, then pass the arguments to `Game.___init__` or at least to a dedicated `Game.from_cli_args` classmethod.

Comment: It's possible. What errors/problems are you having?

Comment: @DeepSpace Thats how it originally worked. I just would like to use Argparse's functionality (ie the type fields and optional args)

Comment: You can use any `argparse` functionally you want, just do it outside of `Game.__init__`

Comment: `core.py [-h] num_players
core.py: error: the following arguments are required: num_players`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is highly unlikely to be the best design.

The `Game` class should probably not care how it was initialized, and it should probably know nothing about command line arguments. You will be better off parsing the CLI args outside, then pass the arguments to `Game.__init__` or at least to a dedicated `Game.from_cli_args` classmethod.

```
import argparse

class Game:
    def __init__(self, num_players):
        print('Game got {} as num_players'.format(num_players))
        self.num_players = num_players


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("num_players", help="Number of players", type=int)
    ...
    args = parser.parse_args()

    g = Game(args.num_players)
```

Then executing:

```
$ python main.py 2
Game got 2 as num_players
```

If you use `--` as a prefix the argument will need to be passed explicitly:

```
parser.add_argument("--num_players", help="Number of players", type=int)
```

Then

```
$ python main.py --num_players 2
Game got 2 as num_players
```

Comment: This works well. I ended up doing this but in `__main__.py` but works the same.

Comment: Nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

yeah,  you can use argparse inside class constructor.just create parser object and pass all arguments to that object, once you initialise class you can access all arguments using that parser object.

```
class test:
        def __init__(self):
                self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
                self.parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',help='an integer for the accumulator')



        def  test123(self):
                args =  self.parser.parse_args()
                # prints argument
                print(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        x = test()
        x.test123()
```

> output: `Namespace(integers=[1, 2, 3, 4])`